# Problem with binding partition

Tags: mount, bind

I have this line in my `fstab` file:

```
/home/bin /bin none bind
```

However whenever I try to `cd` to `/bin` instead of `/home/bin` I get the old `/bin`.

Any idea why it's not working?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/bin /home/bin none bind
```